# Drupal 7 paragraphs saved before node presave

Tags: drupal, paragraphs

I have created a custom node with a logging field and paragraph field that is a list of items.  Prior to saving the node I want to add to the logging field based on the items in the paragraph that have changed since the previous update.  In my hook_presave for the node the paragraph is already updated and is equal to the one in the node->original.

Any help on where I can get a presave version of the paragraph field?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's hook_entity_presave you are looking for https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7.x

Comment: Better ask Drupal related questions on Drupal Answers https://drupal.stackexchange.com/